# Expectation of the minimum of dependent random variables

Tags: probability, mathematical-statistics, random-variable, expected-value, independence

How do we compute the expectation of the minimum of dependent random variables? In other words, what is the value of $\mathbb{E}[Y]$ in the following case:
$$
\mathbb{E}[Y]= \mathbb{E}\big[\min(X_1,\ X_2,\ aX_1+bX_2)\big]
$$
where $a$ and $b$ are constants.

Comment: How you compute it depends on how you are given the joint probability distribution of $(X_1,X_2).$  Could you provide more information?